# Downsizing header, removing footer entirely

Tags: html, css, user-experience

I am working/designing the front-end (working on the layout html+css, later will use php, mvc pattern) of a website. The website has a header, body, side menu and a footer The layout is ready.

There are a few forms which are unusually long/huge since all fields are necessary and I could not make them any shorter. The form opens in a new page.

Not to scare the user away I am planning to downsize the header on the form template (the design change will only apply to the form templates) and get rid of the footer completely.

I tried looking a few places but did not find how to go it done. In short, I want the site to have all block i.e. header, body, footer but when it comes to the form I would want to downsize the header and remove the footer to make the form look sleeker.

Is there a way to do this?

**Note**: I post no code because I have no problem with the code but the concept.

Comment: Why the PHP tag? This is clearly a styling issue => CSS/HTML related, not PHP - nor jQuery for that matter.

Comment: @Qirel, I was auto suggested php and jquery ... new to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: none` for the `footer`element in CSS rules that only apply to this page (for example in a `style` tag in the head of that page).

Concerning the header, it depends how it is built, if it has a logo, background image, text, menu, whatever. In general you could reduce the `height`, make the logo smaller, hide parts of the text in there etc.

Comment: This works but you just gave me an idea, I think I can use the php engine templating engine to get this done. Thank you for replying/suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also done this thing using angularjs 
ng-include
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body >
     <div ng-include="'header.html'">
     </div>
      <div ng-include="'footer.html'">
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `body` of the page has a class, for example `.no-footer .small-header` or `.form-page`. and then in your CSS stylesheet, use something like this :

```
body.no-footer #footer{
    display:none;
}
body.small-header #header{
    height:50px; 
    /* or whatever you want to apply to make the header smaller */
}
```